# Deploying Syslog server on openshfit

Tags: openshift

We are having Syslog server that is written in C++?  The clients are TCP based. Can I deploy the server on open shift? Will I get HA out of the box? Any pointers will help me to proceed.

Answer (score 0):

Unless your syslog server is going to accept logging connections over ports 80 or 443, then you won't be able to host it on OpenShift.  OpenShift only allows external connections on port 80, 443, 8000, and 8443, which are all http/ws ports.